# Parsec: Skipping first line

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have  written a parsec code which works perfectly for what I want. It parses as expected the following file:

```
4,5
6,7
```

The corresponding code is like this:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Applicative hiding ((<|>))
import Control.Monad

data Test = Test Integer Integer deriving Show

integer :: Parser Integer
integer = rd <$> many1 digit
    where rd = read :: String -> Integer

testParser :: Parser Test
testParser = do
  a <- integer
  char ','
  b <- integer
  return $ Test a b

testParserFile = endBy testParser eol

eol :: Parser Char
eol = char '\n'

main = do
  a <- parseFromFile testParserFile "./jack.txt"
  print a
```

But my actual files are like this:

```
col 1,col 2
4,5
6,7
```

Is there a way to make the above parser, just skip the first line ?

Comment: Yeah, consume `many` not-`\n`s, then a `\n`, then go on your way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
testParserFile = manyTill anyChar newline *> endBy testParser eol
```

`manyTill p end` applies p until `end` succeeds. `*>` sequences two actions and discards the first value.

Note: if your actual file doesn't contain a newline at the end, then you need to use `sepEndBy` instead of `endBy`. However, this could be a result of the Markdown parser on StackOverflow.